What is a good cleaner solvent for aromatic compounds?
What would be a good cleaner/solvent to break up and remove deposits of Triphenylbenzene, that is relatively non-hazardous to use in a physics-type lab?
I've been studying the liquid properties of aromatic organic compounds such as Triphenylbenzene. During one experiment, a stainless steel reaction vessel got covered with a deposit layer of TPB due to working at low pressure and its non-negligible evaporation, even at temperatures much closer to its melting point than the boiling point.
We have already tried isopropanol and acetone with mediocre results. The compound is well soluble in toluene but I'm uncertain regarding using say half a liter of it as a cleaning agent.
The vessel is normally used for liquid and solid-state measurements that don't generate vapors. It contains axes and sensors so a gratuitous flooding with solvent is not possible. We rather need to wipe and scratch the deposits off. The lab has good air extraction, but we can't move the vessel into a fume hood or similar.

As you already seem to know, good solvents for aromatic compounds are other aromatic compounds.

I ended up using Toluene and a kitchen sponge for removing the residue. The sponge decomposed a bit but it was more effective than just wiping. Afterwards I wiped everything with isopropanol to get rid of the gas station smell from the Toluene.
